# Filling missing value using the value located to the closest date to the missing value

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I know how to use groupby method with ffill or bfill to impute the missing values. But my problem here is that I need to first find the closest date in the "date" column to the null value in the "score" column, and if the value in the score column was not null, then impute it with that value. If the value was null, I need to search for another nearest closest date. I can iterate through the rows and do it, but it is very slow.

This is an example f the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'cn': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
      'date': ['01/10/2017', '02/09/2016', '02/10/2016','01/20/2017', '05/15/2019', '02/10/2016', '02/10/2017'],
      'score': [np.nan, np.nan, 6, 5, 4, np.nan, 8]})

    cn  date    score
0   1   01/10/2017  NaN
1   1   02/09/2016  NaN
2   1   02/10/2016  6
3   1   01/20/2017  5
4   2   05/15/2019  4
5   2   02/10/2016  NaN
6   2   02/10/2017  8.0
```

output should be

```
    cn  date    score
0   1   01/10/2017  5
1   1   02/09/2016  6
2   1   02/10/2016  6
3   1   01/20/2017  5
4   2   05/15/2017  4
5   2   02/10/2016  8
6   2   02/10/2018  8
```

How can I do it using groupby method and an apply function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `pd.merge_asof` to get the Series of the closest match and then just `.fillna`. There's some manipulation to make sure things align on index in the end.

```
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date) 

s = (pd.merge_asof(
         df.sort_values('date').reset_index(),            # Full Data Frame
         df.sort_values('date').dropna(subset=['score']), # Subset with valid scores
         by='cn',                                         # Only within `'cn'` group
         on='date', direction='nearest'                   # Match closest date 
                  )
       .set_index('index')
       .score_y)

df['score'] = df.score.fillna(s, downcast='infer')
```

#### Output: `df`

```
   cn       date  score
0   1 2017-01-10      5
1   1 2016-02-09      6
2   1 2016-02-10      6
3   1 2017-01-20      5
4   2 2019-05-15      4
5   2 2016-02-10      8
6   2 2017-02-10      8
```

Comment: @ALoIIz, appreciate your time.  (subset=['score']) means that you groupby the data based on the score?

Comment: @Mary  No, there is no grouping here. It's a merge of the entire DataFrame with the subset of itself where score is not null. The `by='cn'` ensures that the merge only happens within the same value of `'cn'` and then within each group if matches based on the "closest" date. Because we dropped the null values from the right DataFrame we use to merge, the result is to match with the closest date for which 'cn' is the same and the score is not missing.

Comment: @ALoIIz, thanks again. Just to make sure,  I have to groupby the data using the "cn" column. The values in the "score" column in one group can NOT  transfer to another group. Your code does not do this, yes?

Comment: @Mary yes, that's taken care of by the `by` parameter. The merge ensures an **exact** match on that first (so essentially this is *within 'cn' group*). Then once that exact match is done, it finds the single closest match based on the `on` condition. You can see some more examples https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: @ALoIIz, than you. It worked. Would you please let me know what is "score_y" ?

Comment: @Mary you can remove everything after the `.set_index` to see exactly what the output of the merge is. Basically, because there are 2 "score" columns, one from the left frame and one from the right frame, merge appends a suffix `_x` and _y` to denote the columns from the left and right frames respectively. In this case, we want score_y, because that's the one from the right frame, i.e. the the non-missing score within cn group that is closest in date.

Comment: Hi there, I've done the same thing but python get fails to accept the direction element for merge_asof. is there any thought ?